# Changing Notation in Direct Quote

Tags: article-writing, research

Tried asking this on Academia.SE but the mathjax doesn't render.

Direct quote: "...the estimator for the expected logarithmic return, $\hat{\mu} \equiv [\sum_1^n X_k]/h$, will have the properties that
$$
E[\hat{\mu}] = \mu,
$$
and
$$
var[\hat{\mu}] = \sigma^2/h."
$$

I'd like to change the notation and format in this quote to ``...the estimator for the expected logarithmic return, $\hat{m} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N R_i$, will have the property that
\begin{align*}
E(\hat{m}) & = m \\
Var(\hat{m}) & = \frac{v^2}{T}."
\end{align*}

Do I need to/is it good form to add something like, [notation mine] or [formatting mine]?  I'm thinking from the point of view of someone trying to look up this quote and not being able to find it because of the notation.

Comment: How about putting this in a footnote?